# Make divs with equal heights according to dynamic contents without javascript

Tags: html, css

For a products page I need to show a number of products (an image plus a title below the image). A number of products will be shown on a row and subsequent products on the next rows. The number of images on a row depends on screen size (responsive).

The titles should be vertically aligned on the same height of the page for each product row. Also, the images on one row should be vertically aligned on the vertical centers of the images in the row.

The product images will be loaded from CMS (WordPress) in a later stadium, so aspect ratios will differ.

I have created a JavaScript solution which works perfect… for browsers with javascript enabled. You can check it [here](http://michielvisser.nl/stackoverflow/width.html) and the code is below. But I would like to have a non JavaScript solution, is this possible? I have trouble creating floating `div`s to have equal heights, where the height should follow the height of the image with greatest height.

P.S.: image sizes should be responsive as well, i.e. image width should be a percentage of containing `div`.

The code with JavaScript:

```js
resize_products();
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  resize_products();
}, true);

function resize_products() {
  var img_padding = 10; //SET EQUAL TO MARGIN

  //resize images
  var img_wrapper_dv = document.getElementsByClassName("product-img-wrapper");
  if (img_wrapper_dv.length > 0) {
    var div_width = img_wrapper_dv[0].offsetWidth;
    var ratio = [];
    ratio[0] = 3 / 2; // width /  height
    ratio[1] = 2 / 3;
    ratio[2] = 1;
    ratio[3] = 4 / 3;
    ratio[4] = 3 / 4;
    ratio[5] = 1;
    ratio[6] = 3 / 2;
    ratio[7] = 2 / 3;
    ratio[8] = 1;

    var max_height = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < ratio.length; i++) {
      var img = document.getElementById("product-img" + i);
      var img_width = div_width * Math.sqrt(2 / 3 * ratio[i]) - 2 * img_padding;
      img.style.width = img_width;
      var img_height = img_width / ratio[i];
      if (img_height > max_height) max_height = img_height;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < img_wrapper_dv.length; i++) {
      img_wrapper_dv[i].style.height = max_height + 2 * img_padding;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.product-img {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
}

.product-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  width: calc(20% - 20px);
  /* 5 products in a row */
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  float: left;
}

.product-title {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .product-wrapper {
    width: calc(25% - 20px);
  }
  /* 4 products in a row */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .product-wrapper {
    width: calc(33.33333% - 20px);
  }
  /* 3 products in a row */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .product-wrapper {
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
  }
  /* 2 products in a row */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .product-wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
  }
  /* 1 product in a row */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img0" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img0
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img3" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img4" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x400" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img5" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img6" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img6
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img7" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img7
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img8" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img8
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should take a look at css grid instead of flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** for this.

We can set `display: flex` with `flex-wrap: wrap` on `#container` for starters, then set the width of each `.product-wrapper` as you've already done. That'll take care of equally sizing the product wrappers along rows.

Then we can also use `display: flex` for each `.product-wrapper` and again for each `.product-img-wrapper` to take care of centering things within each product wrapper.

The feature we are taking advantage of here is automatic margins with flexbox.

Basically, `display: flex` on a parent with `margin: auto` on a child will automatically center that child element vertically and horizontally within the parent. Or you can align a child to one side or another by using an automatic margin on the opposite side. For example, to align our titles to the bottom of their parents, we use `margin-top: auto`. But since we want them horizontally centered too, we end up with `margin: auto auto 0 auto`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  width: calc(20% - 20px);
}

.product-img-wrapper {
  /*display: flex;*/
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.product-img-wrapper img {
  /*margin: auto;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.product-title {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto auto 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .product-wrapper {
    width: calc(25% - 20px);
  }
  /* 4 products in a row */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .product-wrapper {
    width: calc(33.33333% - 20px);
  }
  /* 3 products in a row */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .product-wrapper {
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
  }
  /* 2 products in a row */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .product-wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
  }
  /* 1 product in a row */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img0" src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x60" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img0
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/2000x3000" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img3" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img4" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x400" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img5" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img6" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img6
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img7" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img7
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img8" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img8
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

Comment: Look good, alignment is perfect! One question though: in the javascript solution I had created a formula for showing the images in the same size. This means that all images, although different in aspect ratio, have the same mathematical area (so widthxheight is equal for all images). Is there any way to do this with flex? Now the image 300x400 is twice as big as image 200x300.

Comment: Note: I see the difference in size between the images is greater on my 2560x1440 screen than on my 1920x1080 screen.

Comment: Size of images is an issue. When I change one image to 2000x3000 pixels things looks pretty bad...

Comment: @Michiel I am looking around about the equal area effect, but I am guessing that is not possible. You may need to add your JavaScript on top of things for that, but then at least you have a graceful fallback if a user doesn't have JS enabled. What problem do you see with images that are a large size? Too fuzzy? Too sharp?

Comment: Yes you're right about graceful fallback. But large images is really bad. With 2000x3000 images the columns are made 3000 px high.... Check (this link)[http://michielvisser.nl/stackoverflow/solution_cjl750.html]

Comment: @Michiel there were a couple superfluous styles I had that we can actually get rid of to fix that problem with the images. I have commented them out in the snippet above and changed the size of the first couple images to demonstrate a large and small image. The sizing by area deal I cannot think of a solution for only in CSS and have not found anything about it in searching, so I think you are stuck with JavaScript there, sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll be ok with the javascript, this is a nice fallback.

Comment: Hmm... tested it in IE 11. It looks awful. Columns three times the height of the screen. According to caniuse.com IE 11 supports flex partially due to 'large amount of bugs present'.  I think I will dive into it, see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @Michiel off the top of my head I am guessing the problem is that `.product-wrapper` uses `flex-direction: column`, but I am not in a position to test out IE right now. But I'd see if you can replicate the layout without `flex-direction: column`, and see if that fixes it. You could try setting the child elements to `width: 100%` and having `.product-wrapper` be `flex-wrap: wrap`, then fix the vertical centering with some margin changes, to get a similar effect to what `flex-direction: column` does automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example without Javascript, using flexboxes for layout. I just haven't looked at the media queries.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-img-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.product-img-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
}

.product-wrapper {
  min-width: calc(20% - 20px);
  max-width: calc(20% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  /* 5 products in a row */
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.product-title {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .product-wrapper {
    width: calc(25% - 20px);
  }
  /* 4 products in a row */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .product-wrapper {
    width: calc(33.33333% - 20px);
  }
  /* 3 products in a row */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .product-wrapper {
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
  }
  /* 2 products in a row */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .product-wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
  }
  /* 1 product in a row */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img0" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img0
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img3" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img4" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x400" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img5" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img6" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img6
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img7" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img7
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-img-wrapper">
      <img id="product-img8" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" class="product-img" />
    </div>
    <div class="product-title">
      Titel img8
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```